# react-native sort function not working in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

*Hi, I am creating a sorting function using react-native*,

---

I am using **Flatlist** to display the list items. when I run in an emulator and also in a web no error showing in the console but the sort function is not working.

my code is below please check

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import contacts,{ compareNames } from './contacts'
import Card from './Card'
import {
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainwrap: {
    display:'flex',
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingBottom:30,

  },
  txtheading:{
    backgroundColor:'black',
    margin:'auto',
    marginTop:50,
  },
  scollitms:{
    display:'flex',
    flex:1,
    position:'relative'
  }
});
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    showCounter: true,
    contacts:contacts
  }
  toggglecounter = () => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({showCounter: !prev.showCounter}))
  }
  sorting = () => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      contacts: [...prev.contacts].sort(compareNames)
    }))
  }
  renderItem = ({item}) => (<Card key={item.id} {...item} />)
  render() {
      return (
        <View style={[styles.mainwrap]}>
          <View style={[styles.marginfromtop , styles.countfont, styles.txtheading]}>
            <Button style={{ marginTop: 50, zIndex:999}} onPress={this.toggglecounter} title="Toggle Contacts" />
            <Button onPress={this.sorting} title="sort" />
          </View>
         {this.state.showCounter ?
          <FlatList  style={[styles.scollitms]}
            data={this.state.contacts}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.key.toString()}
          />
          : null
          }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

below is the sort function which I am calling

```
export const compareNames = (contact1, contact2) => contact1.name > contact2.name
```

Comment: try to ```extraData={this.state.contacts}``` to FlatList

Comment: i added it below keyExtractor and this error showing in console.Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `.$[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: and when I removed keyExtractor and added extraData  no eero showing but sorting not working

Comment: FYI: The first parameter of `keyExtractor` is the element, not the index. Be sure that is unique among dataset.

Comment: Have you tried to console log your list after sort to see if the problem come from the compare function or flatlist?

Comment: @MahdiN thanks for your reply its always sorting the list, what I am trying to get is when we click on a button it filters, now it's not showing any error messages in the console, but nothing happens when clicking the button, I updated the code please check